# How do i save a random integer as a variable in python?

Tags: python

I'm attempting to make a dice game but since i am relatively new to python I am stuck trying to assign a random integer to a variable.

Ive tried multiple different routes such as

```
import random
min = 1
max = 6

score1=0
score2=0

rand1=int(input(random.randint(min, max)))
rand2=int(input(random.randint(min, max)))

score1=score1+rand1
score2=score2+rand2
```

I expected this to save `random.randint(min, max)` as `rand1` but it prints the random integer and requires the player to enter a value and then assigns the entered value as `rand1`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) as this would rather get the user to input a string. `rand1 = random.randint(min, max)` is all you need.

Comment: Well you are asking for user input with the input() function. Doesn't `random.randint(min, max)` already give you an int? Why are you adding input and another int on top?

Answer (score 2):

Drop the `input`:

```
import random
min = 1
max = 6

score1=0
score2=0

rand1=random.randint(min, max)
rand2=random.randint(min, max)

score1=score1+rand1
score2=score2+rand2
```

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to use input() method

```
rand1=random.randint(min, max)
rand2=random.randint(min, max)
```